# Unexpected nil value for RxSwift map > subscribe

Tags: swift, rx-swift

This is just a sample.

But I can understand such behavior. Why in the first place a variable is not an optional but in the last is an optional.

```
let tapEvent: ControlEvent<UITapGestureRecognizer> = chargingView.rx.tapGesture()
            tapEvent.map { _ in
                return CGPoint()
                }.filter { $0 != nil }.map { $0 } // here Comparing non-optional value of type 'CGPoint' to nil always returns true
                .subscribe { point in
                    print(point.element) // Expression implicitly coerced from 'CGPoint?' to Any
                }.disposed(by: bag)
```

A screenshot to proof.

[image]

The same behavior for this similar code

```
let tapEvent: ControlEvent<UITapGestureRecognizer> = chargingView.rx.tapGesture()
            tapEvent.map { _ in
                return CGPoint()
                }.flatMap { Observable.from(optional: $0) }
                .subscribe { point in
                    print(point.element)
```

I'm not familiar with rx. Thanks.

Comment: It would really help you if you split that line into 5, one for each map/filter/subscribe/etc. Then you can see the result at each step and see where it's not what you expect. Chaining everything into one call may seem "slick" but it's much harder to read and debug.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break that up:

```
let pointArray = tapEvent.map { return CGPoint() }
let filteredArray = pointArray.filter { $0 != nil }
let newPointArray = filteredArray.map { $0 }
let subscribed = newPointArray.subscribe { point in
    print(point.element)
}
subscribed.disposed(by: bag)
```

That may not be 100% perfect but it's good enough for some clarification.

`pointArray` will be an array of non-optional, empty `CGPoint` values.

Since they are not optional, the filter to remove `nil` values is pointless and the cause of the first error. Simply eliminate the `filter`.

Then you map the objects in `filteredArray` to themselves. Again, this is pointless. Remove that second map.

The second error is related to `point.element`. I know nothing of RxSwift and this specific method based on the warning, the `point` parameter of the closure is optional. You probable need to add a `?` before the `.`.

With all of this, your code becomes:

```
let pointArray = tapEvent.map { return CGPoint() }
let subscribed = pointArray.subscribe { point in
    print(point?.element)
}
subscribed.disposed(by: bag)
```

Or a written in your original format:

```
let tapEvent: ControlEvent<UITapGestureRecognizer> = chargingView.rx.tapGesture()
tapEvent.map { return CGPoint() }
    .subscribe { point in
        print(point?.element)
    }.disposed(by: bag)
```

Whether it makes sense to perform the remaining `map` as it is, I have no idea. Seems odd but again, I don't know RxSwift.

Comment: May be it was not so obvious. But I ment the next question. Why  inside subscribe closure point is optional? But in map closure map returns simple point value.

Comment: You will have to look at the documentation for RxSwift and the `subscribe` method to see why the argument passed to the closure is optional.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case input param of filter operator is CGPoint non-optional. Since it's a non optional you cannot compare it with nil.

In second case `.flatMap { Observable.from(optional: $0) }` flattens `Observable<Observable<CGPoint>>` to `Observable<CGPoint>`

In Swift it's equivalent to this:

```
let arrayOfArrays = [[1,2,3,4]]
let array = arrayOfArrays.flatMap{$0} //Output: [1,2,3,4]
```